# Why is this while loop omitting the first iteration?

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop, do-while

I am new to coding and I've been racking my brain over this but really can't explain this to myself:

I have a csv file with a content like this:

```
line1_value1, line1_value2, line1_value3
line2_value1, line2_value2, line2_value3
line3 value1, line3_value2, line3_value3
```

For testing purposes I tried to print out the values with the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Program test = new Program();
    test.printFile();
}

System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\some_file.csv");

public void printFile()
{
    string line;

    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] substrings = file.ReadToEnd().Split(',');

        foreach (var substring in substrings) {
            Console.WriteLine(substring);        
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }        
}
```

But it omits the first line and prints:

```
line2_value1
line2_value2
line2_value3
line3 value1
line3_value2
line3_value3
```

If I do it in a do while loop, it is working like intended:

```
public void printFile()
{
    string line;

    do
    {
        string[] substrings = file.ReadToEnd().Split(',');                

        foreach (var substring in substrings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(substring);
        }
    }

    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This prints:

```
line1_value1
line1_value2
line1_value3    
line2_value1
line2_value2
line2_value3
line3 value1
line3_value2
line3_value3
```

Why is the first line not showing up in the while loop?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Both snippets read the entire file multiple times without any reason. Just use `ReadToEnd()` once or better yet, `ReadAllLines()`. You are just reading the same file over and over again

Comment: I want it to be read line-wise and comma-seperated. So I must do it in two loops, don't I?

Comment: It works with this: string[] substrings = line.Split(',');

Comment: `ReadToEnd` reads the *entire* file, not only one line. You need `ReadLine` if you want to read one line. Besides, you can simply use `ReadAllLines` to read all lines into an array or `ReadLines` to return an `IEnumerable<string>` that will return one line at a time

Comment: But for a program I am trying to write I need each line to be read separately (at least I think I need this). And Microsoft suggests to do it like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/94223t4d.aspx.

Comment: And that's exactly what `ReadLines` does. It returns an `IEnumerable<string>` you can use in a `foreach` but only reads a new line at a time. `IEnumerable<T>` isn't just an interface, it promises that you'll get new values only when you ask for them. Your current code reads the entire file multiple times. As for the link, it's not a recommendation, it's just a tutorial on how to use text file methods

Comment: Great, that helped me a lot, learned some new stuff. Thanks, @Panagiotis Kanavos!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see what you are doing:

```
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
```

So you read the first line from the file. Next, you do this:

```
string[] substrings = file.ReadToEnd().Split(',');
```

You read the remaining part of the file until the end. It does not go back to read the first line you have read and skipped. That's why it isn't working as expected.

I am not sure what the correct behavior should be since your reading doesn't seem to be line based (so why use `ReadLine` in the first place?). You could read yourself until the first `,` you encounter and process further based on that. Or read the entire file if it isn't too big as you are already doing in the second statement.

And further, the `while` loop is nonsense, since you read until the end of the file anyways. There will never be a second iteration!

Comment: Thanks! Actually, thanks to your help, I figured it out like this: 
string[] substrings = line.Split(',');

I (think I) need it to be read line-wise for a little program I am trying to write.

Answer (score 3):

You are reading the first line at this point

```
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
```

You can instead do this

```
while(!file.EndOfStream)
```

Comment: Okay. So what is the problem with that
?

Comment: @PatrickHofman and then the OP reads and splits the *rest* of the file. Effectively, the OP discarded the first line'. A single `ReadToEnd` or `ReadAllLines` without looping would be enough

Comment: No, really @PanagiotisKanavos But why isn't that in the answer?

Comment: And btw, using `while(!file.EndOfStream)` is pointless since there will never be a second iteration.

Comment: I didn't say it's bad my friend, @pumuckl asked a question and I answered it.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are reading first line from file into variable line and never use output.

```
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
```

Then you rest of file to end (but without first line)